# JScrollPane in a JTextPane

Tags: java, swing

I am just a newbie with Java GUI programming and I have huge of a problem, adding a JScrollPane to my JTextPane. I already tryed the examples of oracle and read through a lot of forums. Nothing helped which leads me here finally.

```
 public class DasFenster extends JFrame {



        // Inkludierung der JText's 
        JTextPane textarea = new JTextPane();   
        JTextField input = new JTextField();    

        Main main = new Main();

        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(textarea);

        Font font = new Font("Courier", Font.PLAIN, 12);    

        public DasFenster() {
            getContentPane().add(jsp);
            // Background Image
            Image img1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("C:/Users/admin/Downloads/1600x901_15162_Night_Memories.jpg");
            JLabel btBild = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img1));
            btBild.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 1200, 750));
            btBild.setText("JLabel");
            add(btBild);
            setContentPane(btBild);

            // TextPane konfigurieren
            add(textarea);      
            textarea.setEditable(false);
            textarea.setText(pretext);
            textarea.setBackground( new Color(255,255,255));
            textarea.setFont(font);

            // Text mittig positionieren
            SimpleAttributeSet center = new SimpleAttributeSet();
            StyleConstants.setAlignment(center, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
            StyledDocument doc = textarea.getStyledDocument();
            doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), center, false);      

            // Eingabefeld
            add(input);

            //einbinden der Handler-class
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            input.addActionListener(handler);
```

other class (settings for my frame)

```
DasFenster fenster = new DasFenster();

    fenster.setVisible(true);
    fenster.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    fenster.setSize(1200, 750);
    fenster.setTitle("someTitle");
    fenster.setLayout(null);        
    fenster.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    fenster.textarea.setBounds                                      (400, 80, 400, 500);//435
    fenster.input.setBounds                                         (400, 600, 400, 30);//500
```

Comment: When you have the text area in a scroll pane, *do not* add it to anywhere else. Ie, remove the line `add(textarea);`.

Comment: .... but **do** add your JScrollPane object to the GUI -- very basic stuff -- have you gone through the scrollpane tutorial yet?

Comment: ok i removed the "add(textarea);". I also tried to implement the textarea in the JScrollPane, but i failed many times. Could you tell me how I do it the right way? Also Iam sorry, that my coding looks so terrible. I tryed so much things, that it got kind of messi.

Comment: I suggest that you remove `setLayout(null)` and all `setBounds(...)` code. While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are **extremely** difficult to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes (as you're seeing), they look poor when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

Comment: I apreciate your suggestion. But reseting my layout and setBounds, does't solve my problem :( (also i dont know which layout would be the best for my programm). Also I tryed the following: JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  panel.add(textarea);
  JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(panel, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
  add(jsp);...and it doesent help either, the textarea dosen't appear anymore :(